# Mobile Hotspot Replaces Site Address With Incorrect IP

Tags: mobile, ip, http-status-code-504

On some of our web apps, when a user connects via a Verizon 5510L Jetpack mobile connection the site address is replaced with an incorrect IP address, and of course throws a 504 error.

Has anyone else ever experienced this? or know why this is happening?

We have other apps that are very similar, on the same server that do not have this issue. Unfortunately this is a popular device with our customer so avoiding the hardware is not an acceptable fix.

As a workaround, the user can connect to the site via a different connection, keep the browser open and connect to their mobile device. This Also is not an acceptable fix as the applications are often used in remote areas.